# How do i configure a c++ sdk in intelliJ?

Tags: c++, ide, sdk, intellij-idea

I downloaded the c++ plugin for intelliJ from http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1373

and the sdk from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en

but I cant seem to set up the sdk correctly in intelliJ. Code isnt recognized, not even the standard library headers like:

```
#include <iostream>
```